# Azure WebJob DB Connection Error Only on some instances

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, dbconnection, azure-sql-database

I have two Azure WebJobs.  The first takes an incoming message that tells it to grab a PDF and break it into individual page images and then queue another message for the second WebJob to process the individual pages.  It worked fine on our QC instance, but when we tried to move to production I started getting strange errors on the second job, but not consistently.  The first job runs and breaks the file into page images.  That is working fine.  I have confirmed that every page image gets created and every page message gets queued.  However, for the second job, only some of the messages are getting processed correctly.  The remaining show this error in the WebJob diagnostics:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessBatchPage ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

But what's weird is that this error mentions the Local Database Runtime and SQL Server Express and I am not references either anywhere in my code.  The system points at an Azure SQL DB.  The job is ADO.Net and I have hardcoded the connection string to try to eliminate any issues with configuration based connection strings.  But what's weird is that it only happens to a certain portion of the messages.  The others process perfectly.

Lastly, I ran the job in debug locally (still pointing at the real queue and DB on Azure) and got the same problem.  But the job outputs a console line with the job ID as the first line of the code.  For those jobs that process successfully, I see this writeline.  For those that fail, I never see anything.  It's almost like the job is not really starting up correctly.  (the failed jobs also have a really short run time 50-100ms)

Comment: Can you post the app.config that's being deployed to Azure? If you're using EF, can you post how you set the connection string?

Comment: Not using EF at all.  I had trouble with EF in the webjob, so I rewrote with just straight ADO.net.  It has a SQLConnection statement with a hardcoded connection string.  Previously I had the CS in the app.config, but hard coded it in the webjob functions.cs to try to eliminate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with some jobs and I've came accross these articles to find a solution:

- [Transient Fault Handling (Building Real-World Cloud Apps with Azure)](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling)
- [Connection Resiliency / Retry Logic (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx)

*From theses articles :*

**Causes of transient failures** :

In the cloud environment you’ll find that failed and dropped database connections happen periodically. That’s partly because you’re going through more load balancers compared to the on-premises environment where your web server and database server have a direct physical connection. Also, sometimes when you’re dependent on a multi-tenant service you’ll see calls to the service get slower or time out because someone else who uses the service is hitting it heavily. In other cases you might be the user who is hitting the service too frequently, and the service deliberately throttles you – denies connections – in order to prevent you from adversely affecting other tenants of the service.

**Use smart retry/back-off logic to mitigate the effect of transient failures**:

The Microsoft Patterns & Practices group has a [Transient Fault Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440719(v=pandp.60).aspx) that does everything for you if you’re using **ADO.NET** for SQL Database access (not through Entity Framework). You just set a policy for retries – how many times to retry a query or command and how long to wait between tries – and wrap your SQL code in a using block :

```
public void HandleTransients()
{
   var connStr = "some database";
   var _policy = RetryPolicy.Create < SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy(
    retryCount: 3,
    retryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    using (var conn = new ReliableSqlConnection(connStr, _policy))
    {
        // Do SQL stuff here.
    }
}
```

When you use the **Entity Framework** you typically aren’t working directly with SQL connections, so you can’t use this Patterns and Practices package, but Entity Framework 6 builds this kind of retry logic right into the framework. In a similar way you specify the retry strategy, and then EF uses that strategy whenever it accesses the database.

> To use this feature in the Fix It app, all we have to do is add a class that derives from DbConfiguration and turn on the retry logic.

```
// EF follows a Code based Configuration model and will look for a class that
// derives from DbConfiguration for executing any Connection Resiliency strategies
public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EFConfiguration()
    {
        AddExecutionStrategy(() => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I am using ADO.net and adding the TFHAB code did seem to clear up this error.  While I should have been using it anyway, the error it returned related to SQL Server Express sent me on a wild goose chase!